# PDFBOX Printing : Printed PDF contains Junk characters for Arabic text from the PDF

Tags: pdf, pdfbox

I have a PDF file containing Arabic text and a watermark. I am using PDFBox to print the PDF from Java. My issue is the PDF is printed with high quality, but all the lines with Arabic characters have junk characters instead. Could somebody help on this?

Code:

```
    String pdfFile = "C:/AresEPOS_Home/Receipts/1391326264281.pdf";
    PDDocument document = null;
    try {
    document = PDDocument.load(pdfFile);
    //PDFont font = PDTrueTypeFont.loadTTF(document, "C:/Windows/Fonts/Arial.ttf");
    PrinterJob printJob = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob();
    printJob.setJobName(new File(pdfFile).getName());
    PrintService[] printService = PrinterJob.lookupPrintServices();
    boolean printerFound = false;
    for (int i = 0; !printerFound && i < printService.length; i++) {
        if (printService[i].getName().indexOf("EPSON") != -1) {
            printJob.setPrintService(printService[i]);
            printerFound = true;
        }
    }
    document.silentPrint(printJob);
    } 
    finally {

      if (document != null) {
     document.close();
      }
}
```

Comment: Which pdfbox Version, what is your code, do you have an example pdf?

Comment: Thanks for comment : PDFBox Version : pdfbox-1.8.4 Following is my code :

Comment: Can you provide an example pdf to reproduce the issue?

Comment: Thanks mkl!.I am happy to provide example PDF,but I believe, I cant attach here. Can I send to your email or can you please provide some link where I can post. Thanks

Comment: Most often people share such samples here using their Google or drop box account. If that's not possible for you, you'll find an email address in my profile here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### In essence

Your PDF can properly be printed using PDFBox 2.0.0-SNAPSHOT but not using PDFBox 1.8.4. Thus, either the Arabic font in question requires a feature which is not yet supported in PDFBox up to version 1.8.4 or there was a bug in 1.8.4 which meanwhile has been fixed.

### The details

Printing the OP's document using PDFBox 1.8.4 resulted in some scrambled output like this

[image: section from scan of 1.8.4 print-out]

but printing it using the current PDFBox 2.0.0-SNAPSHOT resulted in a proper output like this

[image: section from scan of 2.0.0-SNAPSHOT print-out]

In 2.0.0-SNAPSHOT the `PDDocument` methods `print` and `silentPrint` have been removed, though, so the original

```
document.silentPrint(printJob);
```

has to be replaced by something like

```
printJob.setPageable(new PDPageable(document, printJob));
printJob.print();
```

Comment: Osome, Thanks mkl, I will get PDFBox 2.0.0-SNAPSHOT and try to test in my application. Thanks a ton again.

Comment: If you are content with an answer to one of your questions, please accept it (click on the mark left of the answer).

Comment: Hi mkl, PDFBox2.0.0-SNAPSHOT's minimum requirement is java1.6 , my application is on 1.5. Is there any way I can get this one compiled with 1.5.Gr8 if you can comments on this. Thanks

Comment: I'm afraid I don't know (At work we had been bound to 1.4 for quite a long time and directly switched to 1.6 from there. Thus, I have no real first-hand experience with 1.5 specific stuff). You might want to make this a question in its own right.

Comment: @mkl Hey, sorry to hijack this comment-thread... But care to explain exactly how to silent print? There is no such class as `PDPageable` in the 2.0 snapshot. I've tried creating a `PDFPrinter`, with the doc in the constructor, then calling `silentprint()` on it... Causing a StackOverflow, since I'm not on Mac OSX's main cocoa-thread (wat?) Wasn't the idea with silentPrint not to cause any GUI interactions etc. Appriciate the help. Regards

Comment: @RobinJonsson *There is no such class as PDPageable in the 2.0 snapshot* - Well, there **was** such a class in the 2.0.0-SNAPSHOT one year ago... I'll try to find out how to do that using the current SNAPSHOT.

Comment: @RobinJonsson At first glance it looks like the `PDFPrinter` method `silentPrint` meanwhile indeed is the method to use for silent printing. I'm not on a Mac, though, so I cannot reproduce your issue. You may want to make that a question in its own right, providing some code and the stack trace.

Comment: @mkl Thanks mate, I think I'll do that.